# Is there any simple and easier away to write this javascript condition?

Tags: javascript

My condition is working, but i believe there is a more elegant and short way to write it:

```
  if (this.filters.provider.length !== 1) {
    return true
  } else {
    if (this.filters.provider.includes('test')) { return false }
    return true
  }
```

Comment: `this.filters.provider.length !== 1 || !this.filters.provider.includes('test')` !?

Comment: Yes, there is: `if (this.filters.provider.includes('test') && this.filters.provider.length === 1) { return false } else { return true }`

Comment: If you ever have `if (condition) return true`, it can always be simplified to `return condition`

Comment: Is the condition really correct, if length !==1 then return true, so how can the condition this.filters.provider.includes('test') ever be met ?
EDIT: Aaaah, it is an array, not a string :)

Comment: Is the `length` condition required? Currently it looks like `if (filters[0] === 'test' && filters.length === 1) return false else return true`. Can you please eleborate on when true and false have to be returned. Might be an [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: @MikNiller if `"test"` is the only element in the array, it returns false

Comment: @adiga - Yes, first saw it as a string which also has an includes method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return this.filters.provider.length !== 1 || !this.filters.provider.includes('test');
```

Comment: Or just `return this.filters.provider.length !== 1 || this.filters.provider[0] !== "test";`, since the second condition is only checked if the length is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a ternary operator like this:

```
return (this.filters.provider.length !== 1) ? true : this.filters.provider.includes('test') ? false : true;
```